# React JS: onChange Dynamic TextField

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Hello I just started learning react and I am trying to pass data from a response to my TextField dynamically, I did it but it seems that the TextField is not editable (onChange function doesn't seem to work).

This is my state hooks:

```
 const [passParamData, setPassParamData] = useState([]);
```

This is the function that I use to fetch data from a response (using axios):

```
const retrievePassParam = useCallback(() => {
    PasswordMaintenanceService.retrievePassParameter()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("PasswordMaintenancePage - retrievePassParam response.data >>> " , response.data)
        console.log("PasswordMaintenancePage - retrievePassParam JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        setPassParamData(response.data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("PasswordMaintenancePage - retrievePassParam catch >>> " + err)
      })
    });
```

Below code is where I pass the data from a response to a dynamic TextField

```
 {
        passParamData.map(({paramID,value, index}) =>{
        return(
          <div key={paramID}>                       
          <TextField       
            label={paramID} 
            variant="outlined" 
            value={value} 
            onChange={event => {handleTextChange(paramID)}}
          />               
          </div>
       )             
       })
     }
```

This is my onChange function:

```
 const handleTextChange = useCallback((paramID, event) =>{

const inputVal = [ ...passParamData];
inputVal[paramID] = event.target.value;
setPassParamData(inputVal)
```

});

Are there any other ways for the dynamic textfield to become editable? I'm really stuck in this, any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your onChange is not working is because you are passing only one parameter to your function and receiving 2 in the function.

```
<TextField       
  label={paramID} 
  variant="outlined" 
  value={value} 
  onChange={handleTextChange(paramID)}
/>
```

and then you can receive it in `handleTextChange` as a double arrow function.

```
const handleTextChange = (paramID) => (event) => {
  const inputVal = passParamData.map((p) => {
                               if(p.id === paramID) {
                                  return {
                                     ...p,
                                     value: e.currentTarget.value
                                  }
                               }
                               return p;
                           });
  setPassParamData(inputVal)
};
```

Additionally, you are using useCallback but didn't give any dependency. Try to give all the dependencies in `useCallback` or remove it all together.

```
const handleTextChange = useCallback((paramID) => (event) => {
  const inputVal = passParamData.map((p) => {
                               if(p.id === paramID) {
                                  return {
                                     ...p,
                                     value: e.currentTarget.value
                                  }
                               }
                               return p;
                           })
  setPassParamData(inputVal)
}, [passParamData]);
```

Comment: Hi, text field is still not editable after I apply the changes you stated. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: How about if I change the TextField to Checkbox? Would it be the same?

Comment: I think you'll need to check `value: e.currentTarget.value` to `value: e.target.checked`